# Formidable form not sending end event with error Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START

Tags: android, node.js

I am new to node.js . I have created a node.js server which accepts post  requests .
I am using phonegap android application to send image on local server.

error: Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START

Snippet of code is as shown below . 
My `form.on('end' ...`  is not getting called and there by my image is not getting uploaded on to the server

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) { 

                console.log("Upload Code Hit!")

                var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
                form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
                                console.log("Upload Code Hit2222!")
                                res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                                res.write('received upload:\n\n');

                                res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));

                                console.log(" form. parse ends ")
                        });
                console.log("33333!")
                form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
                        console.log(" form.in(end) hit ")
                        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
                        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
                        /* The file name of the uploaded file */

                        var file_name=this.openedFiles[0].name;
                        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
                        var new_location = './uploadedFOlder/';

                        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                                } else {
                                console.log("success!")
                                }
                                });
                        });

                        console.log("88888")


return;



});
```

on my screen i see

```
Upload Code Hit!
33333!
88888
Upload Code Hit2222!
 form. parse ends
```

ie I am not getting the log

```
console.log(" form.in(end) hit ")
```

which gives me impression that the end event is not getting fired . However I have waited for 30 min & image is captured by camera in low quality.  I am using phonegap android application to send image on local server & so i belive even 30 in for local server is too much .

What am i missing ?

**EDIT1:**

I added a code

```
  form.on('error', function(err) {
                 console.log('ERROR!'+ err);
                res.end();
          });
```

and it shows

```
ERROR!Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START
```

can some one please help me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: no answer since Aug 13, did you resolve this issue

Comment: -1, Did you ever solve this ? It is one of the top search results and has not been updated in 4 years with whether this was resolved or did you give up.

Comment: Sorry guys . It was a small part time project i was working on  .  I never picked that project back up .